# getting the x axis grid to show in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

This code plots specific columns in a Pandas Dataframe And provides for multiples:

```
area_tabs=['12']
nrows = int(math.ceil(len(area_tabs) / 2.))
figlen=nrows*7 #adjust the figure size height to be sized to the number of rows
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 25,figlen 
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows, 2, sharey=False)
for ax, area_tabs in zip(axs.flat, area_tabs):
    actdf, aname = get_data(area_tabs)
    lastq,fcast_yr,projections,yrahead,aname,actdf,merged2,mergederrs,montdist,ols_test,mergedfcst=do_projections(actdf)
mergedfcst.tail(12).plot(ax=ax, title='Area: {0} Forecast for 2014 {1} \
 vs. 2013 actual of {2}'.format(unicode(aname),unicode(merged2['fcast']  [-1:].values),unicode(merged2['Units'][-2:-1].values)))
```

with a dataframe that looks roughly like: With date as an index

```
           Units    fcast
date        
2014-01-01   384     302
2014-02-01   NaN     343
2014-03-01   NaN     396
2014-04-01   NaN     415
2014-05-01   NaN     483
2014-06-01   NaN     513
```

I get a plot that looks like:
The horizontal background grid (Units) shows fine but I can't figure out how to get the vertical monthly grid to show. I suspect it may be treated as a minor? but even then can't see where to specify it to pyplot/matplot?

[image]

Comment: is there a reason you're making two axes when `len(area_tabs) = 1`?

Comment: yes because this is test code that will eventually have a range of tabs (20+)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding `ax.xaxis.grid(True, which=['major'|'minor'|'both'])` inside of your `for` loop should do the trick.

The main thing here is that you avoid `plt` state machine functions where possible and operate on the axes objects directly.

#### Edit:

Don't take the above code snippet too literally. The pipe-seperated values are just the options presented in pseudo-regex. If you want the major ticks, use: `ax.xaxis.grid(True, which='major')`

Comment: whacky, if I put ax.xaxis.grid(True, which=['minor']) or if I use major, (or if I use your code exactly.. in the 1st line of the for loop I get an error AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower' from in matplotlib and if I just use ax.xaxis.grid(True)  no change

Comment: using your code directly I get TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: @dartdog "minor" and "major", etc are just the options. Don't use that literally.

Comment: That is what I thought but I got the "no attribute" error using each by itself

Comment: @dartdog that's because you had them in a list when the function expects a scalar strimg

Comment: that did it thanks>>> ax.xaxis.grid(True, which='both')